# How to merge rows in mysql based on an operation between columns

Tags: php, mysql, merge, row

I have the following table

```
tbl
|city| district| start_num| end_num|
|a     |b        |10       |19|
|a     |b        |20       |29|
|a     |b        |30       |33|
|c     |d        |34       |40
|c     |d        |41       |59|
|c     |d        |70      |100|
```

I want to have another table where I have merged the rows taking into account:
same city and district and range start end MUSS be continuous.

```
tbl_res should be 
|city |district |start_num |end_num|
|a     |b        |10        |33|
|c     |d        |34        |59|
|c     |d        |70       |100|
```

the idea is to eliminate rows where the range with another row is contiguous ending with one row with a bigger contiguous range.

Maybe looping through php?

Comment: I don't quite understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you explain your expected results in a bit more detail. Why does the "a,b" pairing collapse to one result but "c,d" collapses to two?

Comment: I edited the example. What I want is to only add ranges that are contiguous for the same pair city/district ie for a-b: 10-20 + 21-30 + 31-33. For c-d I can only join the 2 first ranges: 34-40 + 41-59 but not 70-100 since I'll have a "hole" in the range 60-69

Comment: How many rows do you have / expect to have in the table containing all of the data (preprocessed)?

Comment: The original table has over 200K rows; I want to reduce it to the minimum number of rows possible. ie if possible 1 row per city/district combinations; however it will not be possible since not all ranges are contiguous

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I've managed to work this out. Assuming that none of the ranges overlap, I think this works:

```
SET @group = 1, @current:= 0;
SELECT city,district,MIN(start_num),MAX(end_num) FROM (
  SELECT 
    *,
    IF((start_num-@current)=1,(@group),(@group:=@group+1)) AS contiguent_group,
    @current:=end_num 
  FROM `testtable`) AS contiguous
GROUP BY city,district,contiguent_group
```

It should even work if you have two separate contiguous groups within the same city/district combination.